# save() is called once but being executed twice for the first time in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a to-do list which creates a list dynamically as the parameter is changed on the url. And if that list already exists, it renders the list and not create again. But, when I run the code and give it a random route, it basically executes list.save() twice but only for the first time. From the second time, it runs normally. What is happening?

```
app.get("/:customListName", function (req, res) {
    const customListName = req.params.customListName;

    List.findOne({ name: customListName }, function (err, foundList) {
        if (!err) {
            if (!foundList) {
                const list = new List({
                    name: customListName,
                    items: defaultItems
                })
                list.save();

                res.redirect("/" + customListName);
            } else {
                res.render('list', { aajakoDay: foundList.name, listItems: foundList.items })
            }
        }
    })
})
```

[image]

Comment: Video demo: https://streamable.com/thg666

Comment: Strange problem. I read this https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6626. This had to do with nodemon en mongoose. Maybe this issue causes your problem too.

Comment: first of all change your function to ```async``` and use ```await list.save()```

Comment: @Karlan No nodemon was not the problem but it's fixed now thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh thanks to you too, that too worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the redirect is causing the issue

```
res.redirect("/" + customListName);
```

The list.save() itself seems to be async function. So, you are redirecting it before it was actually saved. Now, when it is redirected, it is still not found (not yet saved to DB) and save() is executed again.

Move the response part inside the save() function, if possible (passing another callback function) or use await to wait until its saved and then do a redirect.

Another way would be to redirect to "/" or homepage. 
You can also use async-await feature to resolve the promises and to make the code more cleaner and efficient.

```
app.get("/:customListName",async function(req,res){
     try{
         const customListName = req.params.customListName;
         let listItem = await List.findOne({ name: customListName });
         //if listitem is found in db
         if(listItem){
             return res.render('list',{ aajakoDay: foundList.name, 
             listItems: foundList.items })
         }
         else{
             //create the listItem
             let newListItem = await List.create({name:customListName, items:defaultItems});
             await newListItem.save();
             return res.redirect("/" + customListName);
         } 
     }catch(err){
         console.log("Error: ",err);
         return; 
     }
});
```

You can refer to this blog : https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

Comment: Thanks man, res.redirect WAS causing the problem and I fixed it with                 list.save().then(() => res.redirect("/" + customListName));

Comment: problem was in your list.save(), you were calling asynchronus function as normal function. your res.redirect was called before list.save() finished its job.